# d3.js : How do I access the root node value of a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, d3.js, hierarchical-data

I want to print the name of the root node in my json file, but not sure how to access it. This is the structure of my json:

```
{
"name": "2010",
"children": [
{
    "name" : "White",
    "children" : [
    { "name" : "208", "size" : 2103},
    { "name" : "209", "size" : 1846},
    { "name" : "228.01", "size" : 2059},
    { "name" : "228.02", "size" : 808},
    { "name" : "228.03", "size" : 1267},
    { "name" : "229.01", "size" : 1302},
    { "name" : "229.02", "size" : 484},
    { "name" : "229.03", "size" : 1045}
    ]
    },
```

I want to print the number 2010 with this line of code:

```
  node.append("text")
  .text(function(d) { if  ( d.parent = null ) {return d.name ; } else { return ("hi") ; };  });
```

Right now this line of code returns "Hi" to me, and I don't know how to print the year "2010".

Comment: `.text(root.name)` where `root` is the name of the variable that holds the data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `root` is the name of the variable that holds the data, all you have to do is access `root.name`.